# Method does not exist even method is static

Tags: method, static

Simple Code I am putting, Complex one working :(

```
public class Kat {

public String name;
public Integer age;

 public static void accentureDetail()
 {
     System.debug('Anything to fix bug');
    }
      }
```

Execute

```
Kat d1 = new Kat();

Kat.accentureDetail(); // Not working

d1.accentureDetail(); // Not working
```

Comment: `Kat.accentureDetail();` should compile and run. List the exact error message you are getting.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is static so you cannot reference it from a non static context or through an instance of that class.

Leaving your class as is, this line of code should work:

```
Kat.accentureDetail();
```

You can read more here:

> A class static variable can’t be accessed through an instance of that
>   class. If class MyClass has a static variable myStaticVariable, and
>   myClassInstance is an instance of MyClass,
>   myClassInstance.myStaticVariable is not a legal expression.
>
> **The same is true for instance methods. If myStaticMethod() is a static
>   method, myClassInstance.myStaticMethod() is not legal. Instead, refer
>   to those static identifiers using the class: MyClass.myStaticVariable
>   and MyClass.myStaticMethod().**

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm